# Game Maker Studio, Importing games

Tags: import, game-maker, gml

Is it possible to import a game maker game into game maker studio? Because I want to edit the older verison of the game, that i have saved as an application?!
example: if I have a game that I created an application so I could share it with friends, how do I do it. the current game that I want to import has the file type .exe ive been changing it to .gmx , .gmz , .gmd . and then a weird error message shows up then when im going to edit my game theirs nothing?! please HELP

Comment: Is it your game? If yes, where is the original `.gmk` or `.gm81` project?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have the actual project file (which would have an extension like, for example, .gmx, .gmz, .gm7, .gm8, .gm81, etc.) you cannot do this. The .exe file extension is for applications, which means that GameMaker already compiled it into a an application.

Comment: So there is no way I can do this?!

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an old program called Gamemaker Decompiler.
As far as I know, it can be found here: http://gamemakerblog.com/2011/06/14/gamemaker-8-1-decompiler-released/

It should be able to decompile anything that is not encrypted by GM:S and should give you a  .gmx, .gmz, .gm7, .gm8 or .gm81 project which you should be able to import directly into GameMaker: Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Even if its only a exe from a older game maker version you can export it to game maker studio.

if it is a exe you need first to decompile it using the decompiling tool for older version of game maker.

[Here](http://www.xtremextension.com/?nav=display&file=70) you can found it

I was able to recover all my old working versions and transform then to game maker studio

So now you just need to open Game Maker Studio and in the Import TAG you this form will show you all the options to importing your games.

[image]